# Google Reverse Geocoding - Urban/Rural flag, and Road Type

Tags: reverse-geocoding

Would anyone happen to know if it is possible to obtain or derive the following pieces of information from the Google Reverse Geocoder API?

- Urban Flag

  - I would like to know whether a given point is within an Urban or Rural zone/area.
- Road Type

  - I would like to know the road type of a given point if the point is on a road.  I would like to know whether it is a Major Highway, Secondary Highway, or a regular street.

Thanks!